# Visible property in knockout not working

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to use visible Property for Knockout binding. I have A observable Property "DataContainer" and below is the sample code in the js file. Since multiple ajax calls are happening and in the aspx , i display the div based on the 
condition. Page is functional working as expected after the contents are loaded. Howeever the problem is before the contents are loaded i am able to see all the div tags in the Page.  Please let me know for any help.
I dont want to display all the div tags on the page.

```
function A()
{
  self.DataContainer = false;
  ..
  ..
      //ajax calls
  ..
  ..
     //ajax calls
  ..
  ..
  .. 
    //ajax calls
  ..
  ..
   //ajax calls

  ..

  self.DataContainer =  true;  


}


Sample.aspx
<div id=container data-Bind="visible :DataContainer>
   ...
   ...

  <div data-bind="If : conditon1>
  </div>
   ...

  <div data-bind="If : conditon2>
  </div>

   ..
   ..
   ..
  <div data-bind="If : conditon3>
  </div>


  ..
  ..
  <div data-bind="If : conditon4>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Hej man, statements in data-bind are written in lower case ,and you forgot to close quote.So, it should look like so:
data-bind="if : conditon4", same with visible binding.

Comment: Also, I see that you have ajax calls. Ajax calls are asynchronous, which means your "self.DataContainer =  true; " will possibly trigger before ajax call has been made. I suggest you you either use ajax promise.done or to set in success function of your last ajax method your code for setting DataContainer to true.

Comment: *"I have A observable Property `DataContainer`"* If this property is truly observable, you can't set it using `self.DataContainer = true`. You'll have to call it with its new value: `self.DataContainer(true)`.

Comment: i make the ajax calls with  "async: false". But still lot of data is available manipulate still the div tag is displayed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knockout "if" binding doesn't work with expression in a sortable list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031057/knockout-if-binding-doesnt-work-with-expression-in-a-sortable-list)

Comment: couldn't you just have an observable originally set to false that is set to true when all your ajax calls are complete?   <div id=container data-Bind="visible :DataContainer && allAjaxCallsAreComplete>